# How to run Spock tests in parallel?

Tags: java, multithreading, testing, groovy, spock

A Spock specification looks like:

```
def mySpec(someData) {
    //testStuff
    where: someData << someDataList
}
```

`someDataList` is a list of records that is tested and for each member of this list, the `mySpec` method is run, sequentially. What I want is that the first k members of the list to run a thread, the following k members to run in a second thread and so on... In theory this can be done relatively easy with Executors Framework and `JUnitCore` class (since Spock relies on JUnit).

The problem however is how to inject smaller `someDataList` into the class that has `mySpec` method, because Spock doesn't allow a constructor and JUnitCore wants class name (the class that has the test/specification) and not an instance. An ugly solution would be to make n copies of `mySpec`, each having a distinct smaller `someDataList`, and each to be run by a distinct thread; but this is a very ugly solution.

Is there a workaround for this? Or is there another way of running Spock specifications/tests in parallel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run specs in parallel if your environment (build tool, IDE) supports it. Running features or iterations in parallel isn't currently possible.

Comment: Running features or iterations in parallel isn't currently possible. - Is it in the backlog to support in future?

Comment: There is an issue for it. It remains to be seen how well it can be done, unless/until we break out of the JUnit execution model.

Comment: Did anyone manage to get Maven run Spock tests in parallel? I couldn't. Ref: [Spock mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spockframework/6zNaZXW8dDc)